# Destruction order of variable without a name

Tags: c++, c++11

Can someone please explain why `bar` behaves differently than `foo` in the following code sample?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A { 
    A() { cout << "A"; }
    ~A() { cout << "B"; }
};

void foo() {
        A a{};
        cout << "X";
}

void bar() {
        A {};
        cout << "X";
}

int main() {
        foo();
        cout << endl;
        bar();
        cout << endl;
}
```

Output (gcc 4.8.1, Ubuntu 13.10, compiled with `--std=c++11`):

```
AXB
ABX
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but because it's an rvalue that terminates at the end of the semi-colon, whereas the first one is a local variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All variables have names.

In `bar()`, `A{}` does not declare a variable.  `A{}` is an expression that constructs a temporary `A` object.  Like all temporaries whose lifetime have not otherwise been extended, this `A` object is destroyed at the end of evaluation of the full expression in which it was constructed (informally, this means "at the `;`").

Comment: +1 for "All variables have names". You are correct, `A{}` does not declare a variable, but rather is an expression constructing a temporary that lives only to the end of the full-expression.

Comment: Do you have a page number for the C++ standard where this and the concept of a "temporary" is explained?

Comment: C++11 §12.2 [class.temporary]

Answer (score 1):

In `f`, the destructor of the named object `a` runs at the end of the function (when the print statement will have already run). In `bar`, you're creating a temporary that exists only during the statement in which it is created. So its destructor is called before the print statement.

Answer (score 1):

In `bar`, you are creating a temporary object of `A` whose lifetime is limited to that statement, whereas in `foo`, the lifetime of `a` is for the entire function.

Answer (score 1):

The temporary object defined by `A {};` only lives to the end of the full-expression, i.e. the semicolon. The named object defined by `A a{};` lives to the end of the function body scope.